# preference checkbox: is it automatically updated?

Tags: android, android-preferences

in this tutorial : http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-user-interface-design-building-application-preference-screens/
they talk about the preference state, and the following method checks wether to set the alarm or cancel it, depending on the boolean in `getBackgroundUpdateFlag` :

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    if (TutListSharedPrefs.getBackgroundUpdateFlag(getApplicationContext())) {
        setRecurringAlarm(context);
    } else {
        cancelRecurringAlarm(context);
    }
}
```

So there is another method that should "set" the pref called `setBackgroundUpdateFlag` , but they say :

> Although we’ve added a setBackgroundUpdateFlag() method for completeness, we will not be using this method. Read on to see why.

**So how can we know when the checkBox Preference is checked**, so that the pref state is set to "true", if we don't use the set method? is there something done automatically with the Preference CheckBox item from the XML ?

I don't understand how the pref is updated. ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, preferences state is persisted automatically. You can read that state and you can also add a listener to have your method called back when a preference changes state.

Take a look at the directory /data/data/..your_app../ on your phone, you will see an XML with the saved preferences. (don't know if it can be viewed on non rooted phones).